# CRM - Lock fields in certain view

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In the entity Quote for example, there is a view on the form that shows what products have been selected for the quote, with the ability to view;

Product Name

Price Per Unit

Quantity

Discount

Extended Amount

My issue is that Product Name, Price Per Unit and Extended Amount are locked on the view therefore cannot be changed.

I would like to do the same for discount, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot change the behavior of this default line item view so you have a few options:

- Create your own quote line item view and show that in place of the system view. The drawback here is your view will not allow you to do in-line edits - you would have to open the quote item to edit each entry.
- Create a synchronous plugin on the `QuoteDetail` entity's pre-processing add and update event which is filtered on the discount field. This plugin would simply throw an exception whenever a non-zero amount is attempted to be pushed through. This effectively makes the discount field disabled as any entry will result in an error on save.